# How should i represent a file importer in Domain Driven Design structure?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I have an onion architecture like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvyS5.png

I need to create an importer that will monitor a folder and import files to database.

This importer will run on a Windows Forms application .

The component importer (class) is part of my infrastructure or my domain?

Otherwise how it should be represented following the DDD principles?

Comment: It sounds like infrastructure to me, but I must admit I find this type of architectural style quite kistchy. Sure it has it's merits, but where to implement a component of your system should be obvious, not muddled in design that only appeals to the non-techs of the company...

Comment: The idea behind this design sounds good for me but this kind of doubt let me sad...

Comment: It's not my intention to scare you away from anything here, just don't let things become over-engineered, keep it simple. Two many layers/tiers often leads to maintenance nightmares down the road. Let "Separation of Concerns" be your guide, not fancy architecture graphics you find online.

Comment: I agree with you. This should be simpler...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application service(maybe domain service if i didn't understand your application intents). The intent of your software is **monitoring files**, so you probably have "file" class in your domain, IFileWatcher as an abstraction to the folder watcher and IFileRepository for storege...

the "importer" will use those interfaces. [this](http://blog.kjempekjekt.com/uploads/2009/09/onion.png) is a better image of the onion architecture.

**2 more things;**

The bottom line of onion architecture is a way (an architecture way) to keep your domain clean from **non domain concerns**(for example the application runs in linux or windows, save data in oracle, sql server or file system, UI won't change your domain models and etc...).

I'm a huge DDD fan but i don't feel that your problem worth it(maybe data centric architecture will be better). as @Didaxis said: keep it simple. develop your software as much as simple you can, apply the SOLID principles then you will be alright. when your application growth, you always can to reorganize the project structure(by the way, onion architecture has heavy DI use). so i advice you to keep your application simple and apply SOLID.

**Edit:**
here some articles about when to use DDD and when not:

[Do Either DDD or DDD But Not DDD](http://www.sapiensworks.com/blog/post/2014/01/13/Do-Either-DDD-or-DDD-But-Not-DDD.aspx)

[When To Use Domain-Driven Design](https://shishkin.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/when-to-use-domain-driven-design/)

Comment: Great Old Fox! Tks for reply.

Answer (score 2):

Any integration should be implemented in the application layer and not in the domain.  So according to the onion architecture (or anything else) it would be infrastructure.

I tend to think of the domain as I would a physical calculator.  A calculator has input (keypad) and it has output (screen).  So the domain would never physically interact with resources outside of the domain.  Everything the domain needs would be passed to it from the application layer and the results would be handled by the application layer.

So even though actual database access, using persistence-oriented repository for instance, and file access may be in infrastructure the application layer is what would perform the calls to get the objects, or put them together, before they are acted upon by the domain.

When I use the term layer it is more of a logical concern than a physical layer.  The physical structure will depend on a couple of factors and include a good dose of preference :)

So in your case your Windows form may very well act as the application layer.  It certainly is the integration point.  However, the physical implementation should ideally rely on some re-usable assembly that may be used from, say, a Windows service or even a web site.

Comment: Awesome Eben! Tks for reply.